# Problem running flutter app in web getting chips_choice_null_safety error

Tags: flutter

I keep getting the error below whenever I run `flutter run` and can't seem to find a solution online.

```
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/chips_choice_null_safety-2.0.6/lib/src/widget.dart:506:56: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                                       ^
../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/animations.dart:97:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(this.value);
```

Comment: That package failed static analysis. Don't use it. See [here](https://pub.dev/packages/chips_choice_null_safety/score). There are alternative packages, such as [choice](https://pub.dev/packages/choice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i recommend you to dont use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/chips_choice_null_safety) package,because  have analysis issues and didn't pass the static analysis  on pub.dev

this is something you can do manually or replace it by [this package (chips_choice)](https://pub.dev/packages/chips_choice)

Comment: The chips_choice package is fine, but the developer said it's no longer maintained, and recommends using [choice](https://pub.dev/packages/choice) as the replacement.